# How do I tell cucumber where to search for files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

In my cucumber step definitions, I want to use constants defined in `"#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/constants.rb"` and `FactoryGirl` factories defined in `#{Rails.root}/spec/support/factories"`. How do I configure cucumber to look in those places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in the initializer are loaded automatically when the Rails application starts. The [same applies](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb) to factories, as long as the `factory_girl_rails` is added as dependency to the environment that is used by cucumber to run the scenarios (generally `cucumber`).

Comment: The constants in the initialiser don't appear to be available to the step definition. When I run cucumber, it complains that they're uninitialised, but I can use them perfectly well from within models and migrations.

Note that the directory for my factories is the RSpec one -- I don't want to repeat the factories for Cucumber.

Comment: If you check the FactoryGirl source code, you'll notice it will lookup the factories in several different folders. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb#L12-L18

Comment: None of which is the folder I specified :) Still, I'll give you credit for the answer, because you confirmed that the behaviour I expected was the standard behaviour, and led me to chase down issues in my gemfile, environment.rb and env.rb files, and I can move my factories to somewhere FactoryGirl does look.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the extra `/support` folder inside `spec` :)